# Location of SWIG src and shared lib files

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, swig

I am using SWIG to use some C functions from python

My platform is linux/ubuntu

I have successfully generated the `example.py` file and built the `_example.so` shared library

Now the problem I have is getting python to 'find' the `_example.so` file

I am attempting to set the relevant search dirs via my `~/.bashrc` file

I have included the dir containing example.py i.e.

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/me/swig_project/src/"
```

the `_example.so` resides in a separate build dir, so I have also set:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/home/me/swig_project/build/"
```

when I run the following from the cmd line I can see the expected dirs are present, i.e.

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

I have re-run `ldconfig` a few times as I thought that might be the issue, I've also logged out and logged back in again.

but I still get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named _example
```

so my python code with the import statement:

```
import example
```

is finding `example.py` no problem, but can't seem to find `_example.so`

even though I've added the dir containing `_example.so` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

if I stick a copy of `_example.so` in the curr dir it works fine

Comment: Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` `PYTHONPATH` etc. is in general a bad idea. Usually, I do one of two options: 1) Make a post-build step to copy the shared object and generated python source to the desired location. 2) Make a script, say `addpath.py` which searches for the .so file and adds the path using `sys.path.append`

Comment: but it should work right? i.e. .py file in $PYTHONPATH and .so file in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I agree with your comment, but I'm not asking what is best practice here, I'm asking why what I'm doing is failing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the issue, the location of `example.py` *and* the location of `_example.so` have to be specified in `PYTHONPATH`.

Not `example.py` on `PYTHONPATH` and `_example.so` on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as I had wrongly assumed.

Once that had been corrected the `Import Module Error` ceased

I then started getting `undefined symbol` errors, but thats a different question..